# Copy a MongoDB document using Mongoosejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, lodash

Just wondered if there is a quick way to copy a document that already exists in the DB and create a new document with the same values (except of course the _id and __v values).

I have something working but it involves me assigning each field from the found document to the new document. This is not ideal because if the number of "fields" increases in the model I will need to change my code too.

Therefore, I had a go with lodash to `_extend` the two documents but then I have trouble with the `_id` and `__v` "fields" that are included in the original document.

Any suggestions on an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the [`_.omit`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#omit) lodash/underscore method to copy the object without the `_id` and `__v` fields:

```
Test.findOne({_id: 123}, function(err, doc) {
    Test.create(_.omit(doc.toObject(), ['_id', '__v']), callback);
});
```

Comment: interesting - is the callback required in the `_.omit`?

Comment: @tommyd456 The `callback` is for the `create` call, not `omit`, and is optional.

Comment: Oh yes - didn't spot that. Just testing now.